# why selected option is hidden in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-design, material-ui

I made a simple demo of form using react material, in which I have only one `select` field .I used this link to make select option
https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/
using `api` I am able to show label at top (using this `shrink={true}`)and show disabled value using this `displayEmpty`.
so my form look like this without any validation
https://codesandbox.io/s/8x4wnjnrz8

Now i try to validate my form using this plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-form-validator
but my default option is hidden and select box label is also look awkward and with become small

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/8x4wnjnrz8

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
import { FormControl, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  ValidatorForm,
  TextValidator,
  SelectValidator
} from "react-material-ui-form-validator";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ValidatorForm onSubmit={() => {}} className="" autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel shrink={true} htmlFor="age-simple">
            Age
          </InputLabel>

          <SelectValidator
            required
            value=""
            name="name"
            displayEmpty
            validators={["required"]}
            errorMessages={["this field is required", "email is not valid"]}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-simple"
            }}
            input={<Input id="age-simple" />}
            className=""
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </SelectValidator>
        </FormControl>
        <Button type="submit"> submit</Button>
      </ValidatorForm>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three issues that are preventing your select component from working properly.

1. You've created a functional (stateless) component. [Learn More.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
2. The dropdown component is not provided an `onChange`, so when you're selecting an `option`, the component is not doing anything to register this new state.
3. Even if you were storing the dropdown state using an `onChange`, you're passing a null `value={}` to your component.

---

Here's a working solution which contains solutions to those three issues:
https://codesandbox.io/s/j2855wrmq5

Notice that I've converted your functional component to a Class. You can read more about the conversion process [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class).

Now that your component is a Class, it can have state. This means two things, we're now handling the `onChange` event by setting our state to the provided value, and we're injecting this value into our component so it can display your selection value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly,

1. You are unable to see the default value (i.e. None) as selected.
2. Label is messed up.

Below are the reason(s):

1. The selected value you have mentioned is empty string (""). Change it to a valid value (Non Empty).
     But the tweak here is if you have a default value, the validator passes as the set has a valid value. Not sure why you are trying to get the validator in this situation.
2. The way the validator works is slightly different. It accepts TextField component and renders it as select. 
      So label needs to be sent as props.

Below is the sample [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/woy8qk8mzl) (Adding external link as inbuilt snippet runner doesn't support)

Hope this helps